# HsqldbException: user lacks privilege or object not found: TABLE

Tags: java, ms-access, hsqldb

I am trying to connect to a MS Access database using hsqldb in java. I added all the libraries I needed, but in the end I still get an exception: 
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: user lacks privilege or object not found: MESSAGES
Caused by: org.hsqldb.HsqlException: user lacks privilege or object not found: MESSAGES

Code below:

```
    Connection conn = null;
try {
    Class.forName("org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver");
    conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hsqldb:D:/sms4.accdb", "sa", "");
} catch (SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

Statement s = conn.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = s.executeQuery("select * from Messages"); //here is where I get the error
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HSQLDB cannot (as far as I know) open an Access database directly. You will need to use the [UCanAccess](http://ucanaccess.sourceforge.net/site.html) JDBC driver. (It uses HSQLDB in the background, but your Java application never manipulates the HSQLDB "backing database" directly.)

For more information, see

[Manipulating an Access database from Java without ODBC](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21955256/2144390)

Comment: Yup, thank you for the info! I removed Class.forName and modified the next line into: DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:ucanaccess://D:/sms4.accdb") and now everything is ok.